# how can i generate a unique int from a unique string?

Tags: java, casting, unique

I have an object with a String that holds a unique id . 
(such as "ocx7gf" or "67hfs8")
I need to supply it an implementation of int hascode() which will be unique obviously.

how do i cast a string to a unique int in the easiest/fastest way?

10x.

Edit - OK. I already know that String.hashcode is possible. But it is not recommended in any place. Actually' if any other method is not recommended - Should I use it or not if I have my object in a collection and I need the hashcode. should I concat it to another string to make it more successful?

Comment: You can't. There are only so many int values, but infinitely many strings. Therefore, not every string can have its own int hascode. You could compute a unique BigInteger hashcode, though.

Comment: @Ingo, I can't see many uses where BigIntegers would be useful as hash codes. They tend to be, well, too big.

Comment: @Jon, indeed. The strings themselves are perhaps the nearly most compact keys one can get. I added the BigInteger idea just for completeness.

Comment: No, hashcode is recommended all over the place, and used implicitly by several standard containers. If you've a specific reason not to use it for your given problem, then detail it or else people won't know why not just to use the pretty good code behind Java's string hashcode.

Comment: Rule #1: don't write something yourself if the JDK already supplies it. JDK code gets updated all the time, so you might just get a better performing implementation just by updating to a newer Java version. If you write it yourself, not only could it be a lot worse than what the JDK provides (let's be real here: it's you versus a whole team of Sun/Oracle programmers) *and* you take on the burden of maintaining it. Don't try to be smart, just do `String.hashCode()`. You want to optimize your code, chances are there are many other places in your code that would more benefit from optimization.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, you *don't* need to have an implementation that returns a unique value, "obviously", as obviously the majority of implementations would be broken.

What you want to do, is to have a good spread across bits, especially for common values (if any values are more common than others). Barring special knowledge of your format, then just using the hashcode of the string itself would be best.

With special knowledge of the limits of your id format, it may be possible to customise and result in better performance, though false assumptions are more likely to make things worse than better.

Edit: On good spread of bits.

As stated here and in other answers, being completely unique is impossible and hash collisions are possible. Hash-using methods know this and can deal with it, but it *does* impact upon performance, so we want collisions to be rare.

Further, hashes are generally re-hashed so our 32-bit number may end up being reduced to e.g. one in the range 0 to 22, and we want as good a distribution within that as possible to.

We also want to balance this with not taking so long to compute our hash, that it becomes a bottleneck in itself. An imperfect balancing act.

A classic example of a bad hash method is one for a co-ordinate pair of X, Y ints that does:

```
return X ^ Y;
```

While this does a perfectly good job of returning 2^32 possible values out of the 4^32 possible inputs, in real world use it's quite common to have sets of coordinates where X and Y are equal ({0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2} and so on) which all hash to zero, or matching pairs ({2,3} and {3, 2}) which will hash to the same number. We are likely better served by:

```
return ((X << 16) | (x >> 16)) ^ Y;
```

Now, there **are** just as many possible values for which this is dreadful than for the former, but it tends to serve better in real-world cases.

Of course, there is a different job if you are writing a general-purpose class (no idea what possible inputs there are) or have a better idea of the purpose at hand. For example, if I was using Date objects but knew that they would all be dates only (time part always midnight) and only within a few years of each other, then I might prefer a custom hash code that used only the day, month and lower-digits of the years, over the standard one. The writer of `Date` though can't work on such knowledge and has to try to cater for everyone.

Hence, If I for instance knew that a given string is always going to consist of 6 case-insensitive characters in the range [a-z] or [0-9] (which yours seem to, but it isn't clear from your question that it does) then I might use an algorithm that assigned a value from 0 to 35 (the 36 possible values for each character) to each character, and then walk through the string, each time multiplying the current value by 36 and adding the value of the next char.

Assuming a good spread in the ids, this would be the way to go, especially if I made the order such that the lower-significant digits in my hash matched the most frequently changing char in the id (if such a call could be made), hence surviving re-hashing to a smaller range well.

However, lacking such knowledge of the format for sure, I can't make that call with certainty, and I could well be making things worse (slower algorithm for little or even negative gain in hash quality).

One advantage you have is that since it's an ID in itself, then presumably no other non-equal object has the same ID, and hence no other properties need be examined. This doesn't always hold.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that hascodes are not unique by definition.

Comment: can you elaborate more about "have a good spread across bits". I couldnt understand that part/

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot. That was very interesting . Since I really dont know how wide my spread will be or what is the  most frequently changing char, then I will go with the root of using String.hashcode() for my mapping. I think I understand from these comments that this is quite reasonable solution. And if there ever would be a collision in my collection my attorney will contact you. my attorney will reach all of you on this page. meanwhile thanks for the enlightenment.

Comment: Your attorney may point out the disclaimers, and suggest that if there are many collisions (a few won't matter, unless the collection itself is badly written) then it's time to examine the hash in more detail, starting from re-reading the above ;)

Answer (score 13):

You can't get a unique integer from a String of unlimited length.  There are 4 billionish (2^32) unique integers, but an almost infinite number of unique strings.

`String.hashCode()` will not give you unique integers, but it will do its best to give you differing results based on the input string.

*EDIT*

Your edited question says that String.hashCode() is not recommended.  This is not true, it is recommended, unless you have some special reason not to use it.  If you do have a special reason, please provide details.

Comment: Not strictly infinite, but still there are 65536^(2^31) or so (including those using Unicode non-characters and invalid combinations of surrogates), so vastly more than 2 billion.

Comment: Changed to "almost infinite" :-)

Comment: Heh, "infinite" is a strong word :)

Comment: If you can think of a better way of phrasing it, be my guest :-)  Once you've got to "4 billionish" on the one side, "really big" seems kind-of weak...

Comment: "really, really, really, big"? ;)

Comment: Any thoughts on using hashcode for about 20K strings varchar 255? Safe enough?

Comment: +Anmol For that small number of strings, a hash as small as 10 bytes would probably be enough.  If you want to take a standard hash, you could use SHA-256 and use 32 bytes (or, hex-encoded, 64 chars).

Comment: Just to add my 5 cents, this solution I think is a good choice for general use cases. At this moment I generate some scheduled notifications in android, based on the id of the event.(is a unique string provided by firebase). To remove this notifs, before they are shonw I need this unique ID, as the id must be a int, this solution fits perfect for my use case

Answer (score 9):

Looks like you've got a base-36 number there (a-z + 0-9). Why not convert it to an int using `Integer.parseInt(s, 36)`? Obviously, if there are too many unique IDs, it won't fit into an `int`, but in that case you're out of luck with unique integers and will need to get by using `String.hashCode()`, which does its best to be close to unique.

Comment: Using a `long` may be worth considering rather than `int`.

Comment: @Peter `hashCode()` returns an `int`, not a `long`. Otherwise I would have suggested that.

Comment: If this is purely for use in hashCode() the result doesn't need to be unique. I am assuming the OP knows this. ;)

Comment: @Peter True. Hard to determine whether he wants a unique integer, or wants a hash code. If simply a unique integer, `long` or even `BigInteger` would be worth considering.

Comment: I suspect he wants all in one. ;) +1 btw.

Answer (score 4):

Unless your strings are limited in some way or your integers hold more bits than the strings you're trying to convert, you cannot guarantee the uniqueness.

Let's say you have a 32 bit integer and a 64-character character set for your strings. That means six bits per character. That will allow you to store five characters into an integer. More than that and it won't fit.

Answer (score 1):

represent each string character by a five-digit binary digit, eg. a by 00001 b by 00010 etc. thus 32 combinations are possible, for example, cat might be written as 00100  00001 01100, then convert this binary into decimal, eg. this would be 4140, thus cat would be 4140, similarly, you can get cat back from 4140 by converting it to binary first and Map the five digit binary to string

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is assign each letter a value, and each place of the string it's own multiple ie a = 1, b = 2, and so on, then everything in the first digit (read left to right) would be multiplied by a prime number, the next the next prime number and so on, such that the final digit was multiplied by a prime larger than the number of possible subsets in that digit (26+1 for a space or 52+1 with capitols and so on for other supported characters). If the number is mapped back to the first digits (leftmost character) any number you generate from a unique string mapping back to 1 or 6 whatever the first letter will be, gives a unique value.

Dog might be 30,3(15),101(7) or 782, while God 33,3(15),101(4) or 482.  More importantly than unique strings being generated they can be useful in generation if the original digit is kept, like 30(782) would be unique to some 12(782) for the purposes of differentiating like strings if you ever managed to go over the unique possibilities.  Dog would always be Dog, but it would never be Cat or Mouse.