# Hash Function without collision

Tags: c++, hash

Basically I'm using the hash function used in rabin karp.

Same function as in [Fast implementation of Rolling hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711770/fast-implementation-of-rolling-hash) but instead of hashing a string, I am hashing a vector of integers.

```
const unsigned PRIME_BASE = 257;
const unsigned PRIME_MOD = 1000000007;
unsigned hash(const std::vector< unsigned int >& Line)
{
    unsigned long long ret = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Line.size(); i++)
    {
        ret = ret*PRIME_BASE + Line[i];
        ret %= PRIME_MOD;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The problem is that I am getting lots of collisions. Changing prime number can minimize or maximize the collision but I can't avoid it.

Any ideas how to avoid collisions with such function or a better one ?

Comment: It's not possible to avoid collisions with a hash.  If you have no collisions then you don't have a hashing function.

Comment: The goal is to minimize collisions, not eliminate them. You'll always have contention unless you have more possible hashes than possible inputs, which sort of defeats the point of hashing.

Comment: `how to avoid collisions` it is impossible, you can minimize collisions for particular set of data, but the same hash function could fail for another dataset

Comment: Note: In C++ express this as `std::vector<x>` not `std::vector< x >` with additional spacing. That ends up looking bizarre, like shell redirection (`>&`) or a less-than operator.

Comment: A hash function basically takes a big number space and reduces it to a small number space. There can *always* be collisions. Just think about an extreme example, like a function that reduces it's input down to a single base-10 integer. Of cause not every input can be uniquely identified by a single number in the range [0-9] so you'll get colissions. But, it's still a perfectly valid hash function.

Comment: Try some other hash functions from [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed).

Comment: Did you measure the average rate of collisions ?

Comment: There is nothing particularly bad about that hash function. However, in addition to the other points raised in the comments, it's important to realize that collisions may be occurring because you have dupes in the items you are hashing. You should eyeball the values of some of the vectors you are passing in. Perhaps a bug in your program or something unexpected in your data sources is causing you to repeatedly hash, say, the all zeros vector.

Comment: What’s your definition of “lots of collisions?” Can you tell us a bit more about what your workflow looks like?

Comment: Are your input values in a limited range? If so, you might want to consider [Zobrist hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zobrist_hashing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't.

The whole point of a hash is to take an input from a large domain, and produce an output in a smaller domain.

Collisions are, by the very nature of the process, inevitable and unavoidable.

You can [try to reduce their likelihood](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/49550/362966), for some particular class of dataset, but you've already explored doing that.

Comment: For a finite set of inputs, it is possible to generate a [perfect hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) that produces no collisions.

Answer (score -1):

You can make little bit better (decrease the chance of the collisions) to add more hash function. Eg:
create 2 hash function, with different PRIME BASE and PRIME MOD, ans store pair of long long's.

Another problem can be if the Line stores many zero's, so better to add some random (which is fixed after the initialization) shift  to the values. 
E.g with Robin-Karb if you want to calculate 'A' and 'AA' hash its better to add shift value otherwise both of this string hash value will be 0. (I mean if you convert the characters like : f(char c){return c-'A';}

Another interesting topic I think if you choose a good hash function (from random aspect), and your input are also randoms, than collsions shouldn't happen when the number of different item in the Line vector is less than sqrt(range of the hash function), this is the birthday paradox. Your current range is 1e9+7 so the sqrt of this is around 3e4. If you using 2 hash function than the combined range is the multiplication of their ranges.

Comment: Of course I didn't want to said that this technic is help you to avoid collisions, I just said how to little bit decrease the chance in c++. This technic what I suggest used by competitive programming competitions to avoid your code be hacked. More on this : https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/60442 , last section about multiple hashes.

Comment: yes, but in the top I see a c++ code and a question: 
"Any ideas how to avoid collisions with such function or a better one ?"
 Maybe I missunderstand and I thought he/she is looking for smg to decrease the chance of the collision. sorry for that.

Comment: hacked mean, when we have a solution which e.g using Rabin Karp, of course probably it fails some input. So if other constentants can find/generate such an input where our solution fail it calls in the competitive programming "hacked" or "challenged"

Comment: probably here its explained much better : https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/1336 point 3.

Comment: @IstvanNagy "one more thing 1e9+7 the prime what is used in the above c++, is mostly used by competitive programming" - why do you keep bringing up "competitive programming" as if it's a good thing? It really is *not*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl This post proposes not to add two hash functions mathematically but to juxtapose them (a pair of long long). Therefore the output space is bigger effectively

Comment: @JesperJuhl Sorry you missunderstand me. I dont say its a good thing. I just thought his question relates to competitive programming, becuase of this number. Sorry for that. By the way why are you down vote all my question what I asked in this site?

Comment: @Damien That's true, but still, the answer (IMHO) still fails to grasp the underlying problem.

Comment: @JesperJuhl OP asks for a better hashing function. And about the only chance, as you mentioned yourself, is to increase the output space

Comment: @IstvanNagy "why are you down vote all my question" - I am not. I vote on a lot of questions daily. Some up, some down. What questions/answers I vote on depends on what catches my eye. I've voted on some of yours, yes, because I felt they deserved the vote I gave. Nothing personal.